# What are the processes I can't do using emulator in android development?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I was making an android application that uses wifi networks mainly, I knew then that I can't test the application on emulator because I can't connect it to the local network, then I wondered if there are other things I can't do in emulator.

***my question what can't I test with emulator other than connect to wifi?***

Comment: [Here you go](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+emulator+limitations&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS752US752&oq=android+emulator+limitations&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.6307j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry I found the answer I felt too stupid to search in android|developers the official google site.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html

it will be found under "What's not supported"

1. Wi-Fi (except API level 25 system images do support Wi-Fi)
2. Bluetooth
3. NFC
4. SD card insert/eject
5. Device-attached headphones
6. USB

Comment: doesn't it all suddenly makes sense? You are on an **emulator**, the hardware resources you are using are not _yours_, they belong to a host system

Comment: I tried first to search for what android emulator can't do? but I could not find any thing. I thought what if it was stated in google official site in the emulator page under some headline